# SSRS - Teradata multivalue parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, teradata, ssrs-2012

I'm using SSRS with teradata DB, trying to pass multivalue parameter to the DB.

I knew that this is an issue with SSRS & Teradata, but I found something weird. It's possible to pass multivalue param, but only if it's the **first** parameter in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM  ts
WHERE LOT in (?) AND Start_Date >= ? AND Start_Date <= ? AND Program like ?||'%'
```

If I make change and the condition "LOT in (?)" is not the first one, i get error..

UPDATE:
I just notice that the location in the query isn't relevant. What that changed is the order of the parameters in "Dataset Properties" (I'm using microsoft Report Builder):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried a very similar query against TD and this one worked as follows:

```
select * from table_1 where col_1 in (?) and col_2 = ?
```

See pictures below.

Dataset parameters:

!http://oi64.tinypic.com/24zbpft.jpg

Report prompts:

!http://oi63.tinypic.com/2yxmyj7.jpg

Parameter definitions:

!http://oi65.tinypic.com/7295qd.jpg